# It is possible to use DataTables Column Filter Add-on with a Gridview

Tags: c#, jquery, html, asp.net, datatable

I am trying to use the DataTables Column Filter Add-on on a gridview table using an sql datasource but i am not coming up with any luck. I have the gridview render a header and footer but i can not add anything to the footer.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Glossary.aspx.cs" Inherits="Home.Glossary" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title spellcheck="true">Glossary</title>
    <style type="text/css" media="all">
        @import "DataTables-1.9.4/DataTables-1.9.4/media/css/jquery.dataTables_themeroller.css";
        #form1 {
            width: 100%;
        }
    </style>        

        <script src="DataTables-1.9.4/DataTables-1.9.4/media/js/jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="DataTables-1.9.4/DataTables-1.9.4/media/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
        <script src="JQuery-DataTables-ColumnFilter/media/js/jquery.dataTables.columnFilter.js"></script>
         <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#<%=GridView1.ClientID%>').dataTable().columnFilter();
         });
</script>
    </head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">

    <div style="background: #A0A0A0">

        </div>

        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" DataKeyNames="TermText,DefNbr,DefVerNbr" DataSourceID="TedGlossary" 
            EnableSortingAndPagingCallbacks="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged" ShowFooter="true"
             AutoGenerateColumns="False" AutoGenerateEditButton="False" style="margin-right: 0px" Width="100%" Height="382px">               

            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="TermText" HeaderText="Term" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="Term" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="DefNbr" HeaderText="Number" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="DefinitionNumber" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="DefVerNbr" HeaderText="Version" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="DefinitinonVersionNumber" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="DefText" HeaderText="Definition" SortExpression="Definition" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="AmplifyingExplanationText" HeaderText="Amplifying Explanation" SortExpression="AmplifyingExplanationText" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="SeeAlsoText" HeaderText="See Also" SortExpression="See Also" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="AuthoritativeSrcText" HeaderText="Authoritative Source" SortExpression="AuthoritativeSrcText" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="ScopeName" HeaderText="Scope" SortExpression="Scope" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="DomnName" HeaderText="Domain" SortExpression="Domain" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="GovernanceStateName" HeaderText="Governance State" SortExpression="GovernanceStateName" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="LastUpdtTimestamp" HeaderText="Last Updated" SortExpression="LastUpdtTimestamp" />

            </Columns>


        </asp:GridView>
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="TedGlossary" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:Glsry_Taylor %>" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [Glossary] ORDER BY [TermText]"></asp:SqlDataSource>

         </form>

</body>

</html>
```

Here is the CS for the rendering

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace Home
{
    public partial class Glossary : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            GridView1.PreRender += new EventHandler(GridView1_PreRender);
        }
        protected void GridView1_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           if (GridView1.Rows.Count > 0)
           {
             //forces grid to render thead/tbody/tfoot elements 
             GridView1.UseAccessibleHeader = true; 
             GridView1.HeaderRow.TableSection = TableRowSection.TableHeader;
             GridView1.FooterRow.TableSection = TableRowSection.TableFooter;

           }
}
        protected void GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
}
}
```

Here is the HTML output, there is too much for the site to handle i put in pastebin the link is included

http://pastebin.com/2qh2eXWY

Answer (score 0):

In order to add anything to the footer, you need to use `TemplateField` controls rather than `BoundField` controls.  See http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/222381-insert-data-using-gridview-footerrow/ for an example of how to do this.  One thing to note though, the HTML generated by the GridView control will use `<td>` elements in the footer rather than `<th>` elements as expected by the DataTables documentation.